# Our infant drinks almost no breastmilk anymore and gains no weight. What can we do?

Tags: infant, breastfeeding, weight

My 4-month-old kid is not drinking breastmilk nowadays. My wife always goes with breastfeeding only. Until now we didn't give bottle. Even with lots of difficulty some time baby used to drink for 5 min. Whenever we take her for feeding baby finds it and started crying. Sometimes, baby will have breastmilk when she is sleeping that too she will drink for 10 or 1 or 2 min - that depends. We feel like slowly she is gaining weight. We went to a doctor and they said like she became too playful. Have you any suggestions how to overcome it?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Parenting.SE! Do you mean breastmilk?

Comment: What has her health care provider said about this?

Comment: Is it accurate to interpret your post as "My 4-month old baby is now refusing breast-milk"? If so, what does your doctor say/are they concerned? The standard rule is that this site is not for medical advice and a baby loosing weight sounds like a medical concern to me. (If you have not been to see your doctor about this - please do.)
If everything is otherwise medically okay but the struggle is with breastfeeding, La Leche League may be helpful. See here: https://www.llli.org/

Comment: Are you giving the baby a bottle at night but still trying to breast feed through the day?

Comment: Doctor said like she became too playful.and my wife always go with breast feed only.till now we didnt gave bottle. Also sorry for misinteuption.."not loosing weight" actually she is not gaining weight.

Comment: shelton - you have written "not losing weight" and "not gaining weight" and "slowly gaining weight" - I think there needs to be clarity, but also, this feels like a medical question - baby weight gain is essential, and doctors can provide various options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the first thing you need to do is to take your daughter to a doctor and explain the problem. There are many reasons behind this scenario another thing you can do is to try to feed milk with a spoon if the doctor allows you.